# Unfolder and search chronologically in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, search, directory

I have got a Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS with a lot of folders and files.
My goal is to find some old files which I think I know a naming format for them say "%A%.csv" or "*.csv" or "*.xls".

Anyway I want somehow to "unfolder" everything and display chronologically file name + date + details (size etc).

In other words without physically unfolder all the directory, but logically what command should I use to write to txt file all file names with their parameters in chronological order?
Please advise.

Comment: Better provide sample input/output

Comment: Consider the following example - you have a folder which have 140 subfolders and each has 3 - 20 subfolders + files ...
Finally you get the leaves (files) and all I want is to "unfolder them - extract all the files outside all folders and sort them chronologically and write their names + size + data created + date modified to a txt file. Everything without physical unfoldering. Makes sense now?

Comment: Let's take a simple example - your C drive contains some folders, these folders contain files and subfolders etc. I want to extract all your files get their meta data and write it to a txt file. How can I do this without physically unfoldering?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thanks, asked there, I thought people here use it and can help. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

```
$ find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n1000 stat -c "%Y %n + %s + %y"|sort -n|cut -d\  -f2-
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, would you be so kind to explain it?